# World of Tanks on Playstation 4

Tags: world-of-tanks

I am going to buy Playstation 4. I also have an World of Tanks account that was exclusively played on PC. It has over 5 tier X vehicles.

Question is, if I install WoT on PS4, will I be able to play my PC account with my vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, its not possible. Sadly :/

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/526422-is-it-possible-to-transfer-your-pc-account-to-ps4/), this is not possible.  It looks like [Wargaming.net](https://console.worldoftanks.com/support/xbox/kb/articles/275) also says its not possible because the game versions are too different.

Comment: Not good. Now if I log and play on PSX4 other player I interact can be from other platforms... or only PSX4?

Comment: No.  [Only PS4](https://console.worldoftanks.com/support/ps4/kb/articles/259).  I believe the only cross play is between Xbox One and Xbox 360 versions.

Comment: Thank you for reply. That means my PC time will be lost :(